# Wordpress: 100% plugin translation not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation

I created a "site specific plugin" what adds a custom post type to my wordpress instance. I made a `.po` file for it with `PoEdit` and even `Loco Translate` shows that it's 100% translated, but it's not working.

Structure:

```
- plugins
 - mysitecore.php
 - mysitecore
  |
  - languages
   |
   - mysitecore-hu_HU.po
   - mysitecore-hu_HU.mo
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through this a while ago and my solution was this.

The language file's name should be like this :

**plugindomain-hu_HU.po**

and the domain in translation functions needs to be the same as what is previous "-hu_HU.po". So **plugindomain**.

For example : `_e('Text to be translated','plugindomain');`